# MAMP/Sequel Pro - Data loss with Time Machine Backup

Tags: mamp

So this morning MAMP would not open. Said the Table could not b found. To try and restore everything, I restored from a Time Machine backup. The databases were restored, but found the data I entered the last three days was missing from the table. I followed the procedure correctly to restore from Time Machine here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file

Luckily, There was not much data entered th last few days, so i could use the old upload csv files to restore those correctly. When I looked in Time Machine at the 
MAMP/db/mysql files, the ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 had a modified and last opened date four days ago.

My question is there anybody here with experience in MAMP + Time Machine that can explain why last night's backups didn't have the data I entered the last three days? I'm using Innodb storage for my local database. I do realize doing mysqldump every night is the best method of preventing this kind of problem.

Thanks

Comment: I have faced the same issue and would love an answer to this question?

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue now. Lost about two week's worth of data. **Edit:** Found [this explanation](https://serverfault.com/a/495646/453907), which seems reasonable.